# Bounce issue in iFrame inside a web-app on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, html, iframe, bounce

thank you for reading! Here we are. We have an annoying issue with the bounce of the browser. I know that this topic has already been studied in deep but this is a little bit different because there is an iFrame that is messing up all the code. Please give me an advice. Thank you on advance.

So this is the code of the main page:

```
    <!-- Main Content Window-->
    <iframe name="AppWindow" class="AppWindow" id="AppWindow" style="display:none;" src="" onload="AppWindowComplete();"></iframe>
```

This is the code of the iframe:

```
<body>
    <div id ="AppMainContainer">
       <div id='AppCustomHeader'></div>         
       <div id="AppHeader">
           Header of app
        </div>
        <div id ="AppContent">
            Content
        </div>
        <div id="AppBottom">
            Bottom Content
        </div>
        <div id="AppFooter">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In the main page I'm using this line of js

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e) {e.preventDefault()};
```

and it seems to work great, but when I scroll the internal div #AppMainContainer the bounce is present.

I tried to use even the StopPropagation(); but nothing seems to work.

Thank you on advance again guys.

Comment: This may be a far shot, but there has been successful implementations of a small snippet I've written: http://www.hakoniemi.net/labs/nonbounce/. In brief: add class="nonbounce" to #AppMainContainer and then call $.nonbounce();